# Is it possible to load / require only one function form a large Ruby module?

Tags: ruby, function, module, load, require

I wrote a quite big ruby module, it loads in about 3-4 secs. Most of the times I need only one function from it. To speed up things, is it possible to load / require only that particular function form the module?

Comment: 3 to 4 seconds just for loading? That has code smell.

Comment: I have a quite old PC, from 2002. 2.4 GHz P4, SATA hard disk, Arch Linux.

Answer (score 5):

> is it possible to load / require only that particular function form the module?

Nope. Break your monstrous module into several smaller ones.

Comment: I would add: Thanks to Ruby's ability to start, stop and repeat `module` and `class` blocks at any point in required code, this is as trivially easy as putting the often-used method in its own file (namespaced as it was before), and requiring that file.

Answer (score 0):

`load` and `require` have nothing to do with "functions" (BTW Ruby doesn't have functions, only methods) or classes or modules. They simply run a file. If the file takes a long time to run, then `load` / `require` will take a long time.